# Проблема с NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, матрицы

У меня есть матрица

```
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [23, 5, 6]])
```

Я хочу узнать координаты цифры 2 в матрице

```
i, j = np.where(matrix == 2)
print(i,j)
```

Все отлично работает

### НО

Если я создаю матрицу с большим количеством элементов например:

```
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 50, 51, 52, 53]])
```

И хочу вывести координаты цифры 2

```
i, j = np.where(matrix == 2)
print(i,j)
```

Я получаю:

```
    i, j = np.where(matrix == "2")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Как решить данную проблему? Есть ли другой метод для реализации?

Comment: у вас разная длина первого и второго списка. поэтому элементами массива являются не числа, а сами списки. Если вы сделаете их одинаковой длины, все будет работать

Comment: Спасибо, завтро проверю